# Is tan theta positive or negative in this case?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Is the value of tangent of an anti-clockwise angle as seen in the image positive or negative if it is in 4th quadrant?
I know that tangent of a positive angle is positive value but I have learned that in 4th quadrant tan is negative. So where iam going wrong?

Comment: You might want to give a clearer title.

Comment: In this sort of diagram you should always measure $\theta$ anticlockwise from the side (here, the $x$-axis) to the hypotenuse, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a perpendicular from the pointed end of the arrow to the positive direction of $x$ axis.Now,by definition of $\tan\theta=\frac{opposite\space side}{adjacent\space side}$ we  find that $opposite\space side$ is negative as it is in the negative direction of $y-axis$.hence $\tan\theta$ is negative.

[image]

As the violet part is negative,$\tan\theta$ is negative.

Comment: How adjacent side is negative?

Comment: @Chemistry had a typo there...edited it...

Comment: So is it wrong to say that tangent of an anti-clockwise angle is not always positive?

Comment: @Chemistry I think you have made a mistake in giving the arrow direction showing the angle....if its in the counter clockwise direction it must cross the second and third quadrants also....you must give your arrow direction in the clockwise direction....

Comment: @Chemistry I have added an image...it might help....please check it out...

Answer (score 0):

The statement "$\tan\theta$ is positive when $\theta$ is positive" is only true if $\theta$ is in the first or third quadrants. Hence the angle you drew, in the fourth quadrant, has a negative tangent.

And the direction of your arrow denoting the angle is wrong. It always starts on the positive *x*-axis.

Answer (score 0):

By recalling the definition of the trigonometric functions as ratios  of sides, one sees that:

$\tan$ is $\gt 0$ in the 1 and 3 quadrants. ($\cos$  is $> 0 $ in 1 and 4 quadrants.) Thus $\tan$ is $< 0$ in 4th quadrant.